# Sphinx warning: "Duplicate substitution definition name" - where is the error?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

When I build my Sphinx project I get a series of errors like this one -- three times:

```
content/swdocs.rsts:6: WARNING: Duplicate substitution definition name: "copy".
```

sdwocs.rsts contains common definitions. I include it in each ReStructuredText file in my doctree.

Many of the files in the doctree include additional RST files, but those files should *not* include swdocs.rsts, since they are effectively parts of a file that already includes it.

Something has gone wrong with this scheme -- presumably an included RST file that includes its own copy of swdocs.rsts -- but where? The message gives me no clue.

I've tried to find the error the hard way, by looking at every file where it could possibly be, and I've found nothing. Presumably something is wrong about my analysis of the problem, and it is hiding in some place or some form where it "could not possibly" be... but without a more informative message, I'm stuck.

How to get unstuck?

Comment: Exactly what is "this scheme"? This will probably be hard to reproduce without more details.

Comment: I described it in the preceding two paragraphs. In summary: the index.rst toctree contains many RST files, each of which includes swdocs.rsts. Many of the RST files include "second-level" RST files, which do not include swdocs.rsts.

Comment: Yes, but how can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: Search for `swdocs`, not `swdocs.rst`, in each of your toctrees (what you incorrectly call "doctree"). Every time you include it, it is counted, and in your case it is counted three times and duplicated. The preferred way to define terms is with Sphinx's built in [glossary directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-glossary). Create a file name `glossary.rst` in the docs source root, then populate it with terms, and refer to the term using `term`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I found the error. Briefly, I found "include swdocs.rsts" in some second-level files that I missed because they violated a naming convention I defined to distinguish them. /// I looked up Glossary. It's nice to know about but not relevant to what I'm doing: defining substitutions that represent extended characters like HTML's &trade; and &reg;.